# How can I check if a unique value is already in a MySQL table from jFrame?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jframe

I have this on a jFrame Button:

```
label.setVisibility(false);


ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("SELECT Str_Column FROM Table WHERE Str_Column = '"+ jTextField.getText() +"'");

//check for the existance

if(rs.getString("Str_Column").equals(jTextField.getText())){
   label.setVisibility(true);
}

else{
   new frameForSucceedInput.setVisibility(true);
}
```

if the if-case goes true or not always displays the succeed window and thats what i don't want to happen, it tells something about `ResultSet` null cause conflicts so then i tried another way:

```
if(state.execute("SELECT Str_Column FROM Table WHERE Str_Column = '"+ jTextField.getText() +"'")){
   label.setVisibility(true);
}
else{
   new frameForSucceedInput.setVisibility(true);
}
```

the `state.execute("SQL")` method says:

> return true if the query contains results, return false if the query is a update or no contain results

i've tried `rs.next()` and a lot of things like instead of else do another `if(rs==null)` but does not work, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quite generic and lighter way is to use the SQL count function .

```
select count(*) from table where str_Column = ?
```

You will get that way one record with one value and if the value is higher than 0 then you can show the frame.

Note:

1. You should use [prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) so you can set parameters in the query (did you notice the question mark?) instead of concatenating the elements of the query.
2. You shouldn't mix the code related to the presentation (Swing) with the code related to the DB...but I think you will learn it later.

Comment: You can go on  concatenating the parts of the query  but I still recommend you to use prepared statements : that way you get rid of quotes (and escaping them), you don't have to format date a specific way, you get better performence, you prevent SQL injection......